# Scala underscore minimal function

Tags: scala, anonymous-function

Let's create a value for the sake of this question:

```
val a = 1 :: Nil
```

now, I can demonstrate that the anonymous functions can be written in shorthand form like this:

```
a.map(_*2)
```

is it possible to write a shorthand of this function?:

```
a.map((x) => x)
```

my solution doesn't work:

```
a.map(_)
```

Comment: Doesn't make much sense, does it? It's just a NOP.

Comment: this is just an example. it can make some sense in context

Comment: This is a good example of the cases where the overuse (imho) of '_' sugar in Scala really makes it difficult for people to pick up the language.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your first shorthand form can also be written point-free

```
a map (2*)
```

Thanks to multiplication being commutative.

As for `(x) => x`, you want the `identity` function.  This is defined in Predef and is generic, so you can be sure that it's type-safe.

Comment: I think you mean commutative.

Comment: It's a pity that `x=>x` is four characters while `identity` is eight.  This is why I never use `identity`.

Comment: @debilski This stuff isn't easy you know!  Not when there's an 18 month-old fighting for access to the keyboard!

Comment: @Rex `identity` may be 8 letters, but it's still a single identifier and so is easier to parse (for humans and compilers alike)

Comment: @Kevin - If you always use the same letter (e.g. `x`), you can just pronounce the "single identifier" `x=>x` as "identity".

Comment: @Rex the AST would beg to differ... and I still see my eye drawn to that arrow anyway :)

Comment: Sometimes you need to write `identity _` instead of just `identity`.

Answer (score 43):

For the record, `a.map(_)` does not work because it stands for `x => a.map(x)`, and not `a.map(x => x)`. This happens because a single `_` in place of a parameter stands for a *partially applied function*. In the case of `2*_`, that stands for an *anonymous function*. These two uses are so close that is very common to get confused by them.

Comment: Actually the two usages are the same thing, "placeholder syntax." The spec doesn't use the phrase "partially applied"; the change log uses it only for `m _` syntax; Programming in Scala uses it first for `m _` and then for `m(_)`. But `f(_)` is syntactically like `if (_)`. "Partial applications" get help inferring the param type.

Comment: Hum, then I wonder why can't we have something like a `val pFunc = a.map(_)` ?

Comment: @SpiXel You can, but you need to specify `pFunc`'s type. Not that `map` takes a function, so x in `x => a.map(x)` would be a function from `Int` to some type. There's no way to infer what type that would be, therefore, you need to specify the type for `pFunc`, at which point Scala will gladly accept that line.

Answer (score 17):

You should use `identity` function for this use case.

```
a.map(identity)
```

`identity` is defined in **scala.Predef** as:

```
implicit def identity[A](x: A): A = x
```