# Can we improve on my code to swap adjacent array elements in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, swap

I'm learning Scala by working the exercises from the book "Scala for the Impatient". One exercise asks that:

> Write a loop that swaps adjacent elements of an array of integers. For
>   example, Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) becomes Array(2, 1, 4, 3, 5)

I did it in 3 different ways, one of which is as follows.I'm curious if this can be improved as per the comments I've put inline.

```
def swapWithGrouped(a: Array[Int]) = {
  a.grouped(2).map {
    // TODO: Can we use reverse here?
    case Array(x, y) => Array(y, x)
    // TODO: Can we use identity function here?
    case Array(x) => Array(x)
  }.flatten.toArray
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `.flatMap` instead of `.map{..}.flatten`.
You also don't really need to match a single element array, so you could simply use a variable (although I feel that this really depends on the problem, sometimes showing the symmetry in the patterns is nice and makes the intent more explicit).

So :

```
scala> def swapWithGrouped(a: Array[Int]) = {
         a.grouped(2).flatMap {
           case Array(x, y) => Array(y, x)
           case single => single
         }.toArray
       }
swapWithGrouped: (a: Array[Int])Array[Int]

scala> swapWithGrouped(a)  // a is Array(1,2,3,4,5)
res0: Array[Int] = Array(2, 1, 4, 3, 5)
```

The `Array(x,y) => Array(y,x)` is also pretty easy to read wrong, `.reverse` makes the intention more explicit and has the added benefit that you can remove the single-element case.

```
scala> def swapWithGrouped(a: Array[Int]) = a.grouped(2).flatMap(_.reverse).toArray
swapWithGrouped: (a: Array[Int])Array[Int]
```

Comment: `_.reverse` is this a partial function?

Comment: The `_.reverse` notation is a shorthand for `a => a.reverse`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422016/scala-underscore-minimal-function for more info.

Answer (score 2):

No, AFAIK there's no way to bind the patterns to names.  The closest thing to doing that is the @ operator, but it doesn't work on the pattern as a whole - only on parameters.

On the other hand:

```
  def swapWithGrouped(a: Array[Int]) = {
    a.grouped(2).map{ _.reverse }.flatten.toArray
  }
```

should do fine.  I'm assuming you don't care about performance; if you do, the code will need to be very different.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar - It would probably be a lot faster to copy the array and then flip elements in order, using a while loop with no collection library methods at all except maybe for the original copy.  One thing this will avoid is [boxing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Boxing) of the Ints in the array, which for a trivial algorithm like this can dominate execution time.