# Scala underscore: error: missing parameter type for expanded function

Tags: scala, lambda, scala-placeholder-syntax

I recently started learning scala and I was a bit confused by how underscore works. While it in most case gives you convenient anonymous method, sometimes it just confuses compiler (and me).

For example,

This works

```
val randomList = List(1,2,3)
randomList.groupBy(x => x)
```

and this

```
val randomList = List(1,2,3)
randomList.groupBy(_ + 1)
```

but not this

```
val randomList = List(1,2,3)
randomList.groupBy(_)

error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) =>  randomList.groupBy(x$1))
          randomList.groupBy(_)
```

A few similar cases are asked in the forum (i.e [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627117/scala-underscore-error-missing-parameter-type-for-expanded-function)), most of them say this is expanded to an anonymous function like this `x => randomList.groupBy(x)`. I just do not know why the complier knows how to compiler second case but not the third. Also, is there a way to resolve the last case without writing a explicit function?

Comment: This is what you want for the "last case": `randomList.groupBy(identity)`

Comment: `_` is never expanded alone, compiler is trying to find complete expression to expand, the closest is `randomList.groupBy(_)`

Comment: Check this answer for understanding the [rules to govern underscore in anonymous functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125850/what-are-the-rules-to-govern-underscore-to-define-anonymous-function)

Comment: @jwvh Thanks, this works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala underscore minimal function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422016/scala-underscore-minimal-function)