# Scala higher-order function : problem with underscore(_)

Tags: scala

Could someone show me the difference between the 2 implementations of function sequence in my code.

I'm using IntelIJ IDEA with sbt.

```
  def traverse[A, B](a : List[A]) (f : A => Option[B]) : Option[List[B]] = {
    a.foldRight(Some(List[B]()) : Option[List[B]])(
      (x, y) => for {
        xx <- f(x)
        yy <- y
      } yield xx +: yy
    )
  }
  def sequence[A](a: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]] = {
    traverse(a)(x => x) //worked
    //traverse(a)(_) //Expression of type (Option[A] => Option[B_]) => Option[List[Nothing]] doesn't conform to expected type Option[List[A]]
  }
```

I expected the final line to achieve the same, instead it show that I return an Option[List[Nothing]].

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR, `f(_)` does not equal `f(x => x)`

As eloquently explained in this relevant [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4431541/6316508), you're looking at the difference between the "short form" for `anonymous function` versus `partially applied function`.

When `_` is part of an expression that represents a parameter:

```
f(_ + 1)  // f(x => x + 1)
g(2 * _)  // g(x => 2 * x)
```

When `_` is a parameter by itself:

```
f(_)      // x => f(x)
g(1, _)   // x => g(1, x)
h(0)(_)   // x => h(0)(x)
```

Comment: You picked the answer that is misleading or wrong. There is no difference. It would be better if someone explained that `_` expands in the expression that contains it. A bare `_` does not mean `identity`. Try bare `_` in the REPL, you don't see "missing parameter type" but "unbound placeholder".

Comment: @som-snytt, despite the two use cases are both included as examples of `placeholder syntax` in the [Scala spec](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#placeholder-syntax-for-anonymous-functions), we're still seeing very different things they represent (as shown in my examples).  I would even argue that not calling out the difference between the two would lead to unnecessary confusions, and I think the difference described in the referenced answer (perhaps to be viewed more as a technical analogy than a formal assertion) helps clarify things a great deal.

Comment: You may be right. On gitter, I said there may be pedagogical value. I think that people are confused by underscore because they see too many "special cases", so reducing that IMHO is a win. There are a few wrong IMHO descriptions of the syntax, which refer to "enclosing parens" as a rule or mnemonic.